# How to delete range of values of a registery subkey

Tags: vb.net, registry

I am trying to delete IE history of typed links. I found this VB6 code but I want it in VB.Net. Any help please?

```
Function Typed()
    For i = 1 To 100
        se = RGGetKeyValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\TypedURLs\", "url" & i)
        If se <> "" Then List1.AddItem se: List1.ListIndex = List1.ListCount - 1
        DeleteValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Internet  Explorer\TypedURLs\", "url" & i
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in .NET its easier...

```
Sub Typed()
    'get a reference to the registry key
    Dim regKey As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs", True)

    ' enumerate the list of values under that registry key
    For Each value In regKey.GetValueNames
        ' add to listbox
        ListBox1.Items.Add(regKey.GetValue(value))
        ' delete the value from registry
        regKey.DeleteValue(value)
    Next
End Sub
```